# Issue with GMM predict_proba() sklearn function

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian-mixture-model

I'm applying Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM) to a dataset of features with a size of [80, 1024], where 80 represents the batch size and 1024 is the dimensionality of the data. My goal is to cluster these features into 10 distinct groups, so I've set the `n_components` parameter to 10 when initializing the GMM model.

```
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=self.num_classes)
gmm.fit(all_fea.cpu().numpy())
prob = gmm.predict_proba(all_fea.cpu().numpy())
```

After fitting the model to the data, I'm trying to obtain the probability of each sample belonging to each cluster using the `predict_proba` method. However, the output I'm getting appears to be in the form of a one-hot encoded matrix with binary values (0s and 1s) for each class.

What might be causing this issue and how to obtain the actual probability values instead of the one-hot encoded matrix?

```
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=self.num_classes)
gmm.fit(all_fea.cpu().numpy())
prob = gmm.predict_proba(all_fea.cpu().numpy())
```

output

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: I think the return of `predit_proba` simply means that the probability of each sample belonging to a group is 100%. It's certainly not binary value, because the 0s and 1s are float point numbers.

Answer (score 5):

You are not necessarily doing anything wrong - this is largely expected behavior from GMMs; using the example from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0], [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
gm = GaussianMixture(n_components=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
gm.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]])
```

we get the result `array([1, 0])`, i.e. our first datapoint belongs to component #1 and our second one to the component #0. Changing `gm.predict` to `gm.predict_proba` gives essentially the same result (and compatible with what you report):

```
gm.predict_proba([[0, 0], [12, 3]])
# result:
array([[0., 1.],
       [1., 0.]])
```

The means of our 2 components here are:

```
gm.means_
# result
array([[10.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```

So, with some trial and error, we may find some points that get indeed probabilities less than 1.0, e.g.:

```
gm.predict_proba([[5.5, 2]])
# array([[0.50000001, 0.49999999]])
```

but such configurations are *very* unstable; as you can see and experiment yourself, even tiny perturbations will lead us back to the `[1, 0]` or `[0, 1]` regime:

```
gm.predict_proba([[5.51, 2]])
# array([[1., 0.]])

gm.predict_proba([[5.49, 2]])
# array([[0., 1.]])
```

So, this is largely expected behavior, and there is not any *programming* issue here; *theoretical* considerations of why this is happening (or even if it is indeed correct or not), are off-topic here - you may consider opening a relevant question at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).